# SoftLayer SLCLI Object Filter Syntax - Date and Boolean Comparisons

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

***Command #1***

```
slcli call-api Account getUsers --mask=username,secondaryLoginRequiredFlag --filter 'users.secondaryLoginRequiredFlag!=True'
```

- Purpose = Display usernames for all users not required to answer
  a security question upon logging in
- Problem = The object filter with the Boolean comparison doesn't appear to work
- Question = How does one perform Boolean comparisons in the object filter?

***Command #2***

```
slcli call-api Account getUsers --mask=username,successfulLogins.createDate,successfulLogins.ipAddres --filter 'users.successfulLogins.createDate>=2017-01-01T00:00:00-06:00'
```

- Purpose = Display usernames and successful login timestamps for all users who have successfully logged in within the last (roughly) 60 days
- Problem = The object filter with the date comparison doesn't appear to work
- Question = How does one perform date comparisons in the object filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currenlty the object filters using the SCLI are not fully supported it only works with some cases such as this:

```
slcli call-api Account getUsers --mask=username,secondaryLoginRequiredFlag --filter "users.username=sl307608-rcabero"
```

another thing is that it only is working for the equal case, you can verify that in the code:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/CLI/call_api.py#L17-L19

So if you really need the objectFilters the best option is use a python script for that and not to use the scli:

see this article for more information:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

Also you can submit this issue at the Softlayer Python client:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues

But I am not sure that they will fix it soon.

here an example using Python script

```
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

# Filter the users whose secondaryLoginRequiredFlag = false
filterLoginFalse = {"users":{"secondaryLoginRequiredFlag":{"operation":  "!= 1"}}}
# Filter the users whose secondaryLoginRequiredFlag = null
filterLoginNull = {"users":{"secondaryLoginRequiredFlag":{"operation":  "is null"}}}

userLoginFalse = accountService.getUsers(filter=filterLoginFalse)
userLoginNull = accountService.getUsers(filter=filterLoginNull)

users = userLoginFalse + userLoginNull

print (users)

# Filter the users created betwern a derteminated date the date must have the following format mm/dd/YY
filterDate = {"users":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["2/4/2014 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["2/4/2014 10:40:00"]}]}}}
users = accountService.getUsers(filter=filterDate)

print (users)
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I may need to move away from the SLCLI and use a programming language (e.g. Python) to employ the filters I outlined above.

Comment: let me chek if they work for and I will let you know

Comment: if the answer help you please mark it as the correct one :)